Get the NUnit tests that are selected for execution
I am writing an NUnit unit test wrapper around an existing test framework that is cmd based. The existing test framework can take commands such as
runtest=mytest

which runs the test setup, all the test cases, then the test teardown.
runtest=mytest tc=tc1

which runs the test setup, test case 1, then the test teardown.
runtest=mytest tc=tc1+tc2

which runs the test setup, test cases 1 and 2 (in that order), then the test teardown.
runtest=mytest tc=tc2+tc4+tc1

which runs the test setup, test cases 2, 4 and 1 (in that order), then the test teardown.
All of these commands create a .com file with commands to execute, based on what test cases were selected, and then executes said com file.
Now, when I want to wrap this in NUnit, I want to be able to, from Visual Studio Test Explorer, select e.g. tc4, tc2 and tc1, and execute them. The same process needs to be done here, I need to know that it's tc4+tc2+tc1 in order to create the right .com file before anything can be executed.
The design of NUnit is that tc4 finishes before tc2 starts. Is there any way, in SetUp or OneTimeSetUp, for the first executing test case in NUnit to find out which test cases that were selected for execution?
